# Why does MSSQL choose scan in execution plan?

Tags: sql-server, index, execution-plan

Here is my query (It is a Microsoft Axapta Query):

```
(@P1 bigint)
SELECT TOP 1 T1.JOURNALNUM,T1.LINENUM,T1.ACCOUNTTYPE,T1.COMPANY,T1.TXT,
T1.AMOUNTCURDEBIT,T1.CURRENCYCODE,T1.EXCHRATE,T1.TAXGROUP,
T1.CASHDISCPERCENT,T1.QTY,T1.BANKNEGINSTRECIPIENTNAME,
-- *Snipped lots of columns in T1* --
T1.MODIFIEDDATETIME,T1.RECVERSION,T1.PARTITION,T1.RECID 
FROM LEDGERJOURNALTRANS T1 
WHERE (((PARTITION=123123123) AND (DATAAREAID=N'test')) AND (REVRECID=@P1))
```

Current execution plan :

[image]

[Current plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=S1ATnbOhE)

Actually, there is a appropriate index on table.

Index columns : (PARTITION,DATAAREAID,REVRECID)

Fragmentation : 
[image]

I tried index force. This execution plan (index seek+key lookup) is faster than after plan (index scan):

[Force Index Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkrs0-O24)

[image]

[image]

And I tried to :

- UPDATE STATISTICS
- Changed it the column order, for example
  (REVRECID,PARTITION,DATAAREAID)

Why does MSSQL choose clustered index?

Comment: are the data equally distributed  or do you have e.g. 1 mio rows for partition 1 and only a few rows for the other partition numbers? If yes (and you have parameterization on your DB enabled) it could be a parameter sniffing problem, if the very same query (with other parameter values) was executed before.

You can verify this by adding spaces, aliases etc. to your query (so it gets a new execution plan)

Comment: I updated my question. This is a axapta query. @P1 is variable. I run query with parameter value in execution plan. `declare @P1 bigint=5639064671`

Comment: Seems like a estimation issue, probably due to the ~240 columns selected. Why are so many columns returned as a result? Could you add the query plan to [pastetheplan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/). This will help in getting a more complete answer.

Comment: I tried OPTION(RECOMPILE). But same plan again. And @RandiVertongen I added plan in my question.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there a possibility to add the plan with the forced index aswell? That might show the estimation differences

Comment: It is a long shot, but what if you add this one to the query `OPTION(USE HINT ('DISABLE_OPTIMIZER_ROWGOAL'))`? More info on this hint in this [blog](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals) by Paul White

Comment: Try adding dataareaid and partition yourself in the aot revrecid index but putting them after revrecid and see what happens

Comment: @RandiVertongen My version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR), doesn't work USE HINT keyword for me.

Comment: @TomV I tried this index (REVRECID,PARTITION,DATAAREAID) and execution plan choose still clustered index scan.

Comment: @select Could you check if it is a row goal issue by adding `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 4138)` More on that [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4051361/optimizer-row-goal-information-in-query-execution-plan-added-in-sql-se)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Estimates, a huge amount of columns selected and predicate pushdown**

The query's estimates are not accounting for the residual predicate on the scan being of a higher cost than the seek + key lookup to get all these extra columns from the clustered index. This results in the clustered index scan + residual predicate being chosen instead of the index seek.

> My version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (RTM-GDR)

These estimates on predicate pushdown where improved in **SQL server 2016 SP1**

[Update to improve diagnostics for query execution plans that involve residual predicate pushdown in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3190762/update-to-improve-diagnostics-for-query-execution-plans-that-involve-r)

> To improve diagnostics for the scenario that's described in the
>   "Symptoms" section, SQL Server 2016 Service Pack 1 (SP1) introduces a
>   new showplan XML attribute, Estimated Rows Read. This attribute
>   provides the estimated count of rows will be read by the operator
>   before the residual predicate is applied. This update is a complement
>   to KB 3107397.

This adds the  `EstimatedRowsRead=""` to the query plan XML, in your case this would be close or matching the residual predicate if the scan is chosen.

This should fix your issue

---

**Residual predicate example**

[image]

[image]

*Reading 1.2M rows to return 0*

**Index scan query Estimated total cost**

```
EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00449281">
```

**Index seek query Estimated total cost**

```
EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00672858">
```

*Which is higher than the index scan estimations due to not accounting for the residual predicate, and that is why the lesser performing plan was chosen.*

---

**The main solution**

The main solution would be upgrading to at least SP1 to add the:

[Update to improve diagnostics for query execution plans that involve residual predicate pushdown in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3190762/update-to-improve-diagnostics-for-query-execution-plans-that-involve-r)

You should patch sooner and more often, since [SP2 CU6](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4488536/cumulative-update-6-for-sql-server-2016-sp2) is out as of **March 19, 2019**, this would be a far better choice.

Another side note, **SP1** for SQL Server 2016 adds [many additional features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/) such as In memory OLTP, Compression, Columnstore indexes, ....

---

**Other workarounds that may or may not be worth mentioning**

- Selecting less columns if they are not needed
- Adding all these columns to the NC index's included columns
- You could try disabling row goals with `OPTION(QUERYTRACEON 4138)` *(maybe)*
- Using the `WITH(INDEX))` Hint

---

**Comparison with SQL Server 2016 SP1**

when running a query alike yours, forcing the clustered index to be used on a SQL2016 SP1 version:
[image]

**The estimated subtreecost is much higher.**

```
EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="93.6951"
```

Where your estimated subtreecost for the clustered index scan

```
<RelOp AvgRowSize="4788" EstimateCPU="1.36996" EstimateIO="185.267" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00448209" TableCardinality="1245280">
```

**Is low**

```
EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00448209"
```

**With the main difference being**

```
EstimatedRowsRead="1000000"
```

shown when executing the query on the SQL 2016 with **SP1** applied.

**And when testing with the NC index specified**

```
CREATE INDEX IX_PARTITION_DATAAREAID_REVRECID
ON dbo.LEDGERJOURNALTRANS(PARTITION,DATAAREAID,REVRECID);

<RelOp AvgRowSize="980" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Seek" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="1000000">
```

the EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost for the index seek (not total for entire plan) is also low:

```
 EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831
```

and the total estimated subtree cost for my test query is very close to yours

```
EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00657048">
```

Comment: I can't change query, 'cause it is axapta query. I am gonna update my version, and I will try. Thank u Randi.

Comment: I upgraded to SP2 and SQL Server chose my force index. Thanks for help Randi.

Comment: @YunusUYANIK awesome, no problem! Thanks for the update =)